# How can I provide SQL request from wso2 enterprise service bus

Tags: sql, oracle, wso2, enterprise, bus

Hii im using wso2 enterprise service bus to connect to a OracleDataBase. I have succesfuly connected, but now i would like to set a request from a client that is connected to my service bus.

The problem is that i dont find any information on internet about my enterprise service bus, i can find information about other products of wso2 but not mine.

And the another question is what would be the url that my client should use to connect to my servicebus to my datasource.

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hector as I understood your query you are trying to insert/update data to the oracle DB you have configured. To achieve this you will need the DB Report Mediator [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/DB+Report+Mediator). After configuring this mediator you can call it using  a proxy and your client can use the url of the proxy to send the payload. You can refer the example at [2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+361%3A+Introduction+to+DBReport+Mediator) to get an over all idea.

1. [DB Report Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/DB+Report+Mediator)
2. [DB Report Mediator Example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+361%3A+Introduction+to+DBReport+Mediator)